# A setting's value string has to be an exactly one character long

Tags: database, ubuntu, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I recently installed Clickhouse on my pc to work with a huge .csv (9Gb)

I know the columns names in this .csv file, so I easily created the table in the Clickhouse console

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MY_DB

CREATE TABLE MY_DB.MY_TB (
    "RC"   UInt64 NOT NULL,
    "COD"  UInt64 NOT NULL,
    "DESC" Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "CAT"  Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "PREC" Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "SNP"  Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',  
    "GEN"  Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "GSE"  Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "COM"  Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL',
    "CB"   Nullable(UInt8) DEFAULT 0,
    "ED"   Nullable(String) DEFAULT 'NULL' 
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PRIMARY KEY RC
ORDER BY RC
```

But when I try to import the data to this table, I get this error

`Code: 19. DB::Exception: A setting's value string has to be an exactly one character long. (SIZE_OF_FIXED_STRING_DOESNT_MATCH)`

I do this through the following command line in my Ubuntu 22.04.1 console

`clickhouse-client --user=default --password=clickhouse  --receive_timeout=3600  --send_timeout=3600 --connect_timeout=900 --format_csv_delimiter=";" --query="INSERT INTO MY_DB.MY_TB FORMAT CSVWithNames" < data.csv`

Does anyone know why I get this error if I'm not defining any limit for the  number of characters in the strings when I create the table?

Comment: Try single quotes instead `format_csv_delimiter=';'`

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned by Bohemian, this looks like very much like the `--format_csv_delimiter` issue. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/12744

I tested with a newer version of ClickHouse though. Both `--format_csv_delimiter=','` and `--format_csv_delimiter=","` works.